# Is there a way to solve object has no atribute FindAll()?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to build a simple web scraper and keep getting an error for FindAll(). I think my problem might be with BS4. Not too sure...

My code is this:

```
my_url = 'https://www.newegg.ca/p/pl?d=graphics+cards&N=100007708&name=Desktop%20Graphics%20Cards'


uClient = uReq(my_url)

page_html = uClient.read()

uClient.close()

page_soup = soup(page_html, 'html.parser')

container = page_soup.findall('div', {'class':'item-info'})

len(container)
```

I am facing this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/Web_Scraper/Web_Scraper.py", line 12, in <module>
    container = page_soup.re.findall('div', {'class':'item-info'})
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findall'
```

Comment: What have you tried to remove this error?

Comment: I tried the answer that was given and it worked well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error will be solved if you replace `findall` by `find_all`.